# Differentiability proof of exponential function $\sum_{n=0}^ \infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^ \infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

I want to prove that $f$ differentiable on $x$ in $[0,1]$.

I am not clear with using the definition of differentiability.

I can prove it is differentiable at $x=0$. I cannot prove in over the interval or when $x$

is something else.

Comment: Do you know a power series can be termwise differentiated (and integrated) within its interval ofconvergence?

Comment: I guess I now know.

Comment: Well, if you use directly the definition you then *must* be able to justify to sum/substract infinite series. For example, you can do this is the series converge absolutely...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the very definition (you may be required to provide justifications):

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac1{x-x_0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n-x_0^n}{n!}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to x_0}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}+x_0x^{n-2}+\ldots+x_0^{n-2}x+x_0^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx_0^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x_0^n}{n!}=f(x_0)$$

Comment: Apparently the OP didn't like my answer...oh, well.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect that the downvote may have been performed due to the fact that you havent provided justification in your third equality. Just to help the asker, remember 

$$ b^n - a^n = (b-a)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2} b + ... + a b^{n-2} + b^{n-1}) $$

Comment: Ok. this is good. I was thinking this way little bit but I could not get it correctly. Thanks

Comment: I think I understand most part, but why did you start with $n=1$? The given function was from $n=0$ to $n=inf$. I see that you end up with what it was given but I don't know why you started that way and where I can get that idea.

Comment: @kane, when the series kicks in we get zero for $\;n=0\;$ , so that's why that sum begins with $\;n=1\;$ .

Comment: @HenryLebesgue Of course I didn't provide justification for that: it is almost trivial and the OP must do some work of his own. More interesting is the second equality in the second line, which involves interchanging limit and sum. Again, the OP must complete.

Comment: I see. Thanks. By the way do you know why people down vote my question? I may mis some rules here I think.

Comment: @Kane, don't worry too much about it: I also have a downvoter stalker the last few days. It happens to almost anyone here from time to time.

Comment: @user1227849937 Of course: since the series converges uniformly on any compact subset of the reals, this is true also in $\;[-1,2]\;$, say, which allows us to differentiate termwise and way easier than by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}=e^x $
($e^x$ Taylor series)

Comment: I know it is $e^x$ and I think I can prove it by using $e^x$ but I am not fully understanding the process with summation form.